# Angular undefined functions after DI

Tags: angular, function, dependency-injection, undefined

I'm trying to inject a class (currently a mocking) in my component `FirstComponent`
For some reasons, my functions in my CourseServiceMock are undefined eventhough I've declared them here :

CourseServiceMock.ts

```js
import {Course} from "../data/Course";
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import {CourseService} from "./CourseService";

@Injectable()
export class CourseServiceMock extends CourseService{

  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  public get(i: number): Course {
    return new Course("IDID",9,12,"test",i);
  }

  public getAll(): Course[]{
    return [
      new Course("IDID",9,12,"test",1),
      new Course("IDID",9,12,"test",2),
      new Course("IDID",9,12,"test",3),
      new Course("IDID",9,12,"test",4),
    ];
  }
}
```

CourseService.ts

```js
import {ICourseService} from "./ICourseService";
import {Course} from "../data/Course";

export abstract class CourseService implements ICourseService{
  public courses:Course[] | undefined;

  public abstract get(i: number): Course;
  public abstract getAll(): Course[];

  protected constructor() {
    this.courses = [];
  }
}
```

ICourseService.ts

```js
import {Course} from "../data/Course";

export interface ICourseService{
  getAll():Course[];
  get(i:number): Course;
}
```

app.module.ts where I declare my data to inject

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { FirstComponent } from './first/first.component';
import {CourseServiceMock} from "./services/CourseServiceMock";
import {CourseService} from "./services/CourseService";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    FirstComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [
    {provide: CourseService,useValue:CourseServiceMock}
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

first.component.ts where my service is injected

```js
import {Component, Injectable, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {Course} from "../data/Course";
import {CourseService} from "../services/CourseService";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-first',
  templateUrl: './first.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./first.component.scss'],
})
@Injectable()
export class FirstComponent implements OnInit {

  courseService:CourseService;
  maListe: Course[] | undefined;

  constructor(courseService:CourseService) {
    this.maListe = undefined;
    this.courseService = courseService;
    console.log(this.courseService);
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.maListe = this.courseService.getAll();
    console.log(this.maListe);
  }

}
```

[image: console screenshot]

Comment: Probably getAll is not a function...

Comment: Little tip, don’t call your function ‘get’ - this is a reserved keyword in js and already used for getters.

Comment: @MikeOne Sure, thanks for all the great tips ! I'm totally new to JS/TS and I've been mainly coding in Java so I should definitely search for the best practices of JS !

Comment: You’re welcome. Angular is a great framework even though it has a bit of a steep learning curve initially. Your code looks pretty good overall - so good job!

Comment: Hello @Beller, can you elaborate please ?

Comment: @Beller By the way, thanks for not even trying and just showing me how bothersome my question was, not providing any meaningful information. I'd recommend you not interating on StackOverlow if it's only to act this way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had been using `useValue` instead of `useClass` in my app.modules.ts.

Still keeping the thread in case someone would face the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

in the `courseService` you're declaring `getAll` as abstract. meaning, you shall use it only with the service that does inherit from it -> `CourseServiceMock.getAll()` will work.

So you have 2 ways of resolving your problem

#### 1. Removing the abstract

*won't make that much sense*
CourseService.ts

```js
import {ICourseService} from "./ICourseService";
import {Course} from "../data/Course";

export abstract class CourseService implements ICourseService{
  public courses:Course[] | undefined;

  public abstract get(i: number): Course;
  public getAll(): Course[]; // <-- removed abstract 

  protected constructor() {
    this.courses = [];
  }
}
```

#### 2. Using `CourseServiceMock` instead

first.component.ts where my service is injected

```js
import {Component, Injectable, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {Course} from "../data/Course";
import {CourseServiceMock} from "../services/CourseServiceMock"; // <-- Import the correct one

@Component({
  selector: 'app-first',
  templateUrl: './first.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./first.component.scss'],
})
@Injectable()
export class FirstComponent implements OnInit {

  courseServiceMock: CourseService;
  maListe: Course[] | undefined;

  constructor(courseServiceMock: CourseServiceMock) { // <-- use the mock service
    this.maListe = undefined;
    this.courseServiceMock = courseServiceMock;
    console.log(this.courseServiceMock);
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.maListe = this.courseServiceMock.getAll(); // <-- should work
    console.log(this.maListe);
  }

}
```

#### Additional tip

Why are you assigning the service into a new variable, prefer declaring it public or private, so you may use it into your class.

```js
import {Component, Injectable, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {Course} from "../data/Course";
import {CourseServiceMock} from "../services/CourseServiceMock"; // <-- Import the correct one

@Component({
  selector: 'app-first',
  templateUrl: './first.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./first.component.scss'],
})
@Injectable()
export class FirstComponent implements OnInit {
  maListe: Course[] | undefined;

  constructor(private _courseServiceMock: CourseServiceMock) { // <-- declare it public or private
    this.maListe = undefined;
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.maListe = this._courseServiceMock.getAll(); // <-- should work
    console.log(this.maListe);
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try those in a minute ! I'm only discovering typescript, so I didn't know some of the features I'd have. The point of passing an abstract class to the constructor was to decouple my implementation from my code, is it not possible to do so ? Because using my Mock would strongly couple my Component to an implementation and it's considered a bad practice (at least in Java). Or maybe I'm not understanding it all, I'm fairly new to dependency injections

Comment: @Paul You have a nice code, and you can continue with is, but also in java you wouldn't be able to use the `getAll()` function, because you did use the wrong service. So I would ignore the first possibility and opt for the second one.

The public / private stuff is doing the same as you did, but typescript do it automatically for you in the compiling time ;)

Comment: I'm using the abstract type, but I'm actually injecting his child class (in the app.module.ts file), CourseServiceMock, so I feel like i'm definitely not understanding a concept. Even in my screenshot, we can see in the console that a CourseServiceMock is passed (first line of the console). So it feels weird to see that it does not contain any method even though it's proper class

Comment: I've figured the issue I couldn't see the actual content of the console output on Chrome, but I was able to look it up on Firefox. I was using useValue instead of useClass, which was creating an object, and my actual service was in the prototype field (so i couldn't actually use my functions. Using "useClass" solved the issue :) ! 
Thanks anyway for all the tips you gave